# How can I pass a form value to another page when ID is inside <span>?

Tags: javascript, php, url, input, html-table

I have a website that has info on some people, like name, social security number and birthday. When the user clicks a button, it redirects them to https://meu.inss.gov.br/central/index.html#/agenda. What  I need to do is fill out the fields "CPF" and "Data de Nascimento" in this site.

My issue is that the IDs for CPF ("ident-cpf") and Data de Nascimento ("ident-data-nascimento") are inside a "span" tag and a "div" with three diferent states. A few weeks ago, I solved a similar problem, but it was on my website, where I could pass these values through the url, like "'www.website.com/page.php?&id-name="."$name'", for example. I can't (I probably don't know) how to do that in the government website.

Right now, my code is pretty simple:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($vet); $i++){
 echo '<tr>';
  for($j = 0; $j <count($colunas); $j++){
   if ($j == 6 || $j == 9)
    echo "<td><span class='hide'>".$vet [$i][$j]. "</span>".date("d/m/Y", strtotime($vet [$i][$j]))."</td> ";
   elseif ($j == 11){
    $abre = "'https://www2.dataprev.gov.br/sabiweb/relatorio/imprimirCRER.view?acao=imprimir_CRER&nuBeneficioRequerimento=".$vet[$i][11]."&dataNascimento=".$vet[$i][12]."&nomeRequerente=".$vet[$i][2]."&cpf=".$vet[$i][4]."'";
    $abre2 = "'https://meu.inss.gov.br/central/index.html#/agenda'";

 echo '<td><a data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip"  title="Consultar"><button font-size:10px;" class="copiar btn btn-primary btn-xs "  onClick="window.open(' . $abre2 . ')" data-title="Edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">Meu INSS</span></button></a>
<a data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip"  title="Consultar"><button font-size:10px;" class="copiar btn btn-primary btn-xs "  onClick="window.open(' . $abre . ')" data-title="Edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">Data Prev</span></button></a></td>';
```

$abre is ok, because I can get the data from the arrays and then pass to the other website through the URL.

With $abre2, I don't know how to do that, but the data would be pretty much the same.

Comment: What exactly is stopping you from adding query string values to your second URL exactly as you do in the first URL?  (Note of course that the `#/agenda` fragment would have to come *after* the query string, not before it.)

Comment: @David Hi. I tried to add a value in the second URL, but for the field CPF, for example, I need to pass the data through the URL, but I also need to change the state of the div class for this field, which is "campo-formulario" (Portuguse for form-field), then "campo-formulario" and then "campo-formulario  has-content". I'm not sure, but I think I'd need to change the this also? Is it possible to do that?

Comment: What "state" do you need to change?  Where are you trying to change it?  What isn't working?  It's really not clear what specifically you're asking.

Comment: Hi @David
Abre2 (the government website) has the following code on it:
`<div class="campo-formulario  has-content">
 <div>
 <label class="mobileValue" for="ident-cpf">CPF</label>
 <label class="desktopValue" for="ident-cpf">CPF</label>
  <span>
  <input name="ident-cpf" id="ident-cpf" value=""></span>
  </div>
</div>`

What I want to do is this:
`$abre2 = "'https://meu.inss.gov.br/central/index.html?ident-cpf=888.585.585-85#/agenda'"`, so the user doesn't need to type all the info.

Is this possible? Can I send this info to the website so my user doesn't need to type all that?

Comment: That code is just HTML, it doesn't provide any sort of functionality of automation.  Unless there's code on that page which *uses* the query string values, those values will be ignored.  If you're trying to auto-fill forms for a website which has no functionality to do that then what you're looking for is a browser plugin, not a query string.

Comment: @David Alright. About the plugin, do you know if is there any that will get the data from my website or are you talking about one of those that we use to put our e-mail adress, for example, so that we don't need to type it once we are trying to sign up on a website?

Comment: It's unlikely that you'll find an existing browser plugin which does the exact custom functionality you're describing in the question.  But when you write your browser plugin, you can have it do whatever you like.

Comment: @David - Alright, thank you. You saved me a ton of time.